# Python wxImage: Saving Image as wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP

Tags: python, wxpython

i'm trying to save an image that is generated during runtime. this works fine for wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG and ..._PNG but fails for wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP as well as for ..._GIF.

here's the code:

```
imgName = 'test.png'
imgType = wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP
img = wx.EmptyImage(width, height)
[...]
img.SaveFile(imgName, imgType)
```

i've also tried to initialize other handlers via `wx.InitAllImageHandlers()` but that doesn't work either.

`.SaveFile(...)` keeps returning `False` and the generated bmp has the size of 0 bytes although the image should contain data.

is there anything wrong with my code or might there be other issues?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what "fails" means?

Comment: The GIF handler can only load, not save (because of intellectual property issues). The BMP handler is always available and should work, but I don't think it can handle transparency (yet). Does your image have an alpha channel?

Comment: Try creating the image with `wx.EmptyBitmap(width, height, 24)` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: the image has no alpha channel. however, i adjusted Mark's suggestion that made saving work but doesn't work for me because i manipulate the image via `.SetRGB(...)` wich is not supported by the wx.Bitmap-class and i didn't find anything similar. what i do now is generating an EmptyImage (s.a.), manipulating it, then converting it to bitmap using `.ConvertToBitmap(depth)` and finally saving it.